# methodology to handle struct containing uv_tcp_client

Tags: c, networking, libuv

This is not a real question for the C language players and networking programming experts, but a discussion I would like to launch about how to deal with struct containing basic libuv components such as uv_tcp_client or something else.

Let me give a more detailed scenario to begin our discussion. ***uv_read_start*** is a function that we use to read from stream which is linking to server. The third argument is a pointer pointing to a function prepared after reading operation. The prototype of this function is just like:

```
void uv_read_start(uv_stream_t*, alloc_buf_function, after_read_function)
void after_read_function(uv_stream_t*, ssize_t nread,const uv_buf_t* buf)
```

In after_read_function, if nread < 0, which means that some error took place and we have to free uv_stream_t*. So far, we are OK if you only use variable from libuv.

But if you install a user struct containing uv_stream_t*, the situation may become knotty.

```
typedef struct 
{ 
    uv_stream_t* tcp_client;
    ...
} client;

....
client* cli = malloc(sizeof(client));
uv_read_start(cli->tcp_client, alloc_buf_function, after_read_function);
....

void after_read_function(uv_stream_t* tcp_client, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t* buf){
    if (nread < 0) {
       // error take place
       // we should not only free tcp_client, but also the client struct we malloc outside.
       // However, this function is a callback one and type of arguments has been determinated 
       // in libuv source code and I can't bring client into this function.
    }
}
```

So, anyone can help with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @wildplasser nread is the length of buffer which have been read in uv_read_start (this is 
 an API function, not my function). If nread is a negative number, which mean we failed in reading operation. Cleanning action must be taken to clear the struct we allocate.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'll delete...

Comment: when you call `uv_read_start` you are able to specify a callback code in your code, eg, `my_read_cb`, and in there, you can do both the call free up your own application-specific resources, and then do call to `uv_close` to clean up the libuv resource.

Comment: @DarrenSmith Thanks for you comment. Just as I said at very beginning of this post. It is not a real question, but just want ot discuss the doable method. I acutally use global double-link list to store my clients (I pretty sure you must understand that there may be several clients connecting to one server at the same times), and define a function that could return the pointer pointing to the client which contain tcp_client that I am using. And then, just release them both as you suggested.